# Convert <Directory> tag in apache config to nginx

Tags: nginx

hello i have this config in my apache

```
<Directory "/phpmyadmin/">
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

how i can make this code valid for nginx config

this is what i tried

```
location /phpmyadmin {

           Deny All;

        }
```

but when i close my nginx server i got this

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "Deny" in C:\nginx/conf/nginx.conf:49
```

someone know how to fix this ??

Comment: How about [not installing phpMyAdmin](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/security/stop-installing-phpmyadmin)?

Comment: I don't need the solution for phpmyadmjn only let's say I have some files and I need them to be only accessible via script not dirct url

Comment: @DanilaVershinin Does your recipe work with MariaDB as well?

Comment: @IvanShatsky why not. It's only about MySQL GUI clients and connecting via SSH tunneling. This is available in any modern MySQL client and works against any flavor of MySQL server.

Comment: i just used phpmyadmin as a example for my question instead of put my files name so i can get the answer and append it on my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To restrict a directory or multiple directories in nginx conf file, you can do like this:

```
...
location ~ /(dir1|dir2|dir3) {
   deny all;
   return 404;
}
...
```

in your case, you can try like this:

```
...
location /phpmyadmin {
   deny all;
   return 404;
}
...
```

If you want, you can redirect to a specific route too based on the status code.

Answer (score 0):

Apache and nginx share little to none config params. For nginx deny, you go with

```
location /phpmyadmin {
    return 403;
}
```